# Postsharp aspects reach to HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core, aop, .net-7.0, postsharp, aspect

I am using PostSharp, and within my aspects, I want to check a header from the incoming request during the entry phase of a method. I am unable to access HttpContext. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
var httpContextAccessor = args.Instance.GetType().GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

var httpContext = httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext;
```

I tried this, but I couldn't get any results.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core? If so, what version are you targeting, and **where** is this code? PostSharp isn't specific for ASP.NET Core, so your question post needs more detail.

Comment: This is Asp.Net Core. The version is .Net 7. I have an api endpoint and I want to access current HttpContext from the OnEntry method.

Comment: Please share a [mre].